# Output variable number of string values to rows within an excel worksheet

Tags: python

I'm "playing" little bit with python on a beginner level.

My question:

I created a xlsx workbook where I will write data which I have parsed in other files, First I do:

```
myworkbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('MyWorkbook.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('MyWorksheet')
```

Than after parsing my file, I have the data (type: str) of interest stored within my variable "X":

```
print(X)

0x100
0x200
0x300
0x400
0x500
..
..
```

Just for information:

```
print(type(X)):

<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
```

Now I need just to output this data into myWorksheet
The number of string values can be variable each time.
i would like to output all these values one after each other to excel rows starting for example from B5 and than B5++ until there are values.

Something like:

```
worksheet.write_string('B5:Bn', X)
```

Expected output in out.xlsx:

```
B5    0x100
B6    0x200
B7    0x300
B8    0x400
B9    0x500

Bn    0x...
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: what did you try? Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Comment: Why in column B ? Anything there in Column A ?

Comment: After giving an answer I read your question again. I thought you have trouble with the way that you need to access the data within an excel file in python. So as @PatrickArtner mentioned, maybe you can elaborate more so that can help with the exact problem that you encounter!

Comment: @SandeepLade: I released the column A because it's already filled with some static defined strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below using `openpyxl`. Here `ws` is worksheet object

Here column=2 means column B and row starts from 5 and goes till x has values

```
>>> n=5
>>> for i in x:
        ws.cell(row=n,column=2,value=i)
        n+=1
```

If its Ok to append in the next available row , you can use below

```
>>> for i in x:
        ws.append([i])
```

If you are using `xlsxwriter` module use below

```
r=5
for i in x:
    worksheet.write(r,2 , i)          # write_string()
    r+=1
```

And as per your comment X is a string. First you need to convert it to a list to process further

```
>>> x='''0x100
0x200
0x300
0x400
0x500'''
>>> print x
0x100
0x200
0x300
0x400
0x500
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
>>> x=x.split()
>>> type(x)
<type 'list'>
>>> for i in x:
    print i


0x100
0x200
0x300
0x400
0x500
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be exactly what I want to do. The problem is that I get the error: AttributeError: "Worksheet has no attribute cell" or also AttributeError: "Worksheet has no attribute append". I'm also using the newest version of openpyxl. What's wrong?

Comment: which module you are using ? The given syntax is for openpyxl

Comment: @JohnDoe : Updated answer if you are using `xlsxwriter` module. Please check and provide feedback

Comment: Oh, my fault, I mixed the syntax of openpyxl and xlsxwriter!

Comment: @JohnDoe : Check with correct syntax and update the answer if it answers your question

Comment: @Sadeep Lade: It outputs me only the last string which is than distributed across successive rows. For example if the last string is "0x900" it will output me 0 in B2, x in B3, 0 in B4, o in B5. But this seems to be my issue, that the content in X has to be formatted in different datatypes.

Comment: Check type (i) , print i and print x before passing to xlsxwriter .

Comment: type(i) outputs me: 0x1000x2000x3000x4000x500 ...    In the output console the numbers are vertically ordered. The print(type(X)) I have put in my question

Comment: Ok , you a string in variable `x`. First you need to convert `x` to a list. Then you have to process further. Updated my answer for the same. Check it

Answer (score 1):

If you use pandas library then the main data type that you deal with is dataframe and you can also turn it into numpy matrix/array format. Here is an example that can work with excel file using pandas library:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", names=["A", "B", "C", "D"]) # load excel file as dataframe with names for the columns
print(df.columns) # see the columns (first row of your data)

a = df[df.columns] # get the values of all columns in a dataframe 'a'
print(a)
print(a.shape)
print(type(a))

b = df[df.columns].values # get the values of all columns in a matrix 'b' (numpy 2darray)
print(b)
print(b.shape) 
print(type(b))

# sample usage on different data types
print(a['A1'][5:10]) # dataframe
print(b[5:10, 0]) # 2D array
```

If you do not specify the names then the first row will be used as the columns unless you read like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", header=None)
```

So basically you have to get to know dataframes and numpy array structure a bit. To find out more:

- [pandas read_excel documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)
- [10 minutes to Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)
- [Numpy ndarray quick intro](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html)